# Weighted Wilcoxon rank sums

Tags: probability, weights

I want to test for differences in a non-normal continuous variable between group A and B. I want the test to account for the inverse probability density weight (IPW) of being in group A. My own idea was a jonckheere-terpstra test with a weight statement (IPW), but I am not sure that is the best solution. Any ideas/comments would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Papers have been published comparing differences in predicted rank sums: https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/nejmoa1110717

Comment: My question is: how is it possible to weight the wilxon rank sum test by the probability of having a rank sum b given covariable b and category a?

Comment: Another paper you might find helpful:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24132928